# Объявление матриц в MathNet.Numeric

Tags: c#, матрицы

Нужно объявить две матрицы: 1х3 и 3х2 с конкретными значениями, а затем перемножить эти две матрицы.

Скачал библиотеку MathNet.Numerics, но так и не разобрался, как работать с ней.

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развёрнутые вопросы. Для получения ответа поясните, в чём именно вы видите проблему, как её воспроизвести, что вы хотите получить в результате и т. д. Приведите пример, наглядно демонстрирующий проблему.

Comment: На [официальном сайте](https://numerics.mathdotnet.com/) есть примеры.

Comment: @ГеннадийП Благодарю

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну, в самом простом случае (пример с [заглавной страницы](https://numerics.mathdotnet.com/) сайта):

```
Matrix<double> A = DenseMatrix.OfArray(new double[,] {
    {1,1,1,1},
    {1,2,3,4},
    {4,3,2,1}}
    );
```

Сбоку в меню есть пункт [Getting Started - Matrices and Vectors](https://numerics.mathdotnet.com/Matrix.html) - там ещё с десяток примеров создания матриц.

Случайная:

```
var m = Matrix<double>.Build.Random(3, 4);
```

А также - по определённой функции, по гамма-распределению, пустую, диагнональную...