# Нужно пропустить все элементы матрицы через функцию

Tags: c#, матрицы

Возникла проблема: не знаю как пропустить все элементы матрицы через функцию и из этих элементов создать новую матрицу. Использую библиотеку MathNet.Numerics.

Comment: в чем конкретно проблема? Где ваш код, что вы пытались? Что не получилось?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Updated. Коллега @rdorn подсказал более краткий способ, результат будет тот же:

```
var b = a.Map(x => x + 1, Zeros.Include);
```

---

Создайте матрицу [любым способом](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/893985/213987):

```
var a = DenseMatrix.OfArray(new double[,] {
    {1,1,1,1},
    {1,2,3,4},
    {4,3,2,1}}
    );
```

Преобразуйте её данные в Enumerable и модифицируйте Enumerable нужным образом при помощи linq:

```
var b = a.Enumerate().Select(x => x + 1);
```

Создайте новую матрицу из модифицированного Enumerable:

```
var matrixBuilder = Matrix<double>.Build;
var c = matrixBuilder.DenseOfColumnMajor(a.RowCount, a.ColumnCount, b);
```

Как-то так в итоге:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: PS Библиотеку вижу впервые в жизни, час ночи на дворе - если проглядел более подходящие способы - пишите, будет любопытно посмотреть.

Comment: [var b = a.Map(x => x +1, Zeros.Include);](https://numerics.mathdotnet.com/api/MathNet.Numerics.LinearAlgebra/Matrix%601.htm#Map%60%601)

Comment: библиотеку тоже впервые вижу, кстати, весьма неплохая по набору классов и функций, ЛинАл можно решать не думая почти =)

Comment: @rdorn Ага, я чувствовал, что должен быть короче способ! Спасибо за дополнение - внёс в ответ.